# Error: no Snakefile found, tried Snakefile, snakefile, workflow/Snakefile, workflow/snakefile

Tags: snakemake

I had this error whenever running my snakefile.smk
`Error: no Snakefile found, tried Snakefile, snakefile, workflow/Snakefile, workflow/snakefile.`

using ls command shows that the file exists in directory

```
Miniconda3-4.7.12.1-Linux-x86_64.sh   config.yml  miniconda3  nano.save.1    snakemake
Miniconda3-4.7.12.1-MacOSX-x86_64.sh  download.r  nano.save   snakefile.smk  work
```

I am using WSL2 ubuntu 20

the snakefile contents

```
sample = ["GSE6955", "GSE67311"]
rule download:
    output:
        "~/{sample}.tar"
    run:
        "~/download.R"
rule extract:
    input:
        "~/{sample}.tar"
    output:
        directory("~/{sample}")
    shell:
        tar xvf {input}`
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Er, the error message looks  pretty clear. You do understand that `snakefile` and `snakefile.smk` are different filenames, right?

Answer (score 2):

Snakemake by default looks for a file called `snakefile` or `Snakefile` in the working directory if a specific file is not provided.  In your case, your snakefile is called `snakefile.smk`.  To run snakemake with a specific snakefile, you can call it with the `-s` or `--snakefile` command line arg.

I recommend you call snakemake with the `-h` flag to see all the options available when calling snakemake.